# mysql query with 2 object for same table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 Write a SQL query to delete all duplicate email entries in a table named Person, keeping only unique emails based on its smallest Id.

+----+------------------+
| Id | Email            |
+----+------------------+
| 1  | john@example.com |
| 2  | bob@example.com  |
| 3  | john@example.com |
+----+------------------+
Id is the primary key column for this table.


# Write your MySQL query statement below
DELETE p1
FROM Person p1, Person p2
WHERE p1.Email = p2.Email AND
p1.Id > p2.Id
```

This is a SQL question and solution.
My question is: why we need p1 and p2 two objects? What concept here this query is using? Certainly it it not table join sub-query.
I am unfamiliar of this query pattern. Want someone give me some pointers or links about this type of query. thanks

Comment: It is called `SELF JOIN`. You are trying to compare the records with in the table

Comment: so,self join does not require 'joint' keyword, right? @Prdp

Comment: No it can be written using `JOIN` keyword also.  `DELETE p1
FROM Person p1 INNER JOIN Person p2
ON p1.Email = p2.Email AND
p1.Id > p2.Id`. You have used Old style *comma separated join*, which not recommended

Comment: nice. that's why... i was confused because of lacking join keyword. thanks @Prdp!